# Dynamically loaded flash movie is on top of jquery dialog: how to change zorder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, z-order

A flash movie is loaded on a page via javascript (replaceChild on a div)

I add jquery datepicker to a input above this movie.

When the datepicker (or other jquery element) is shown, it is shown under the movie (wrong zorder)

The element do have "z-index: 99" in its css class

How do i bring the jquery element up?

[Edit]

Theres no styling on the flash object tag

This happens on Chrome and IE, on firefox it also happens, but some elements are over the movie (picture)

[alt text http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/5519/capturadetelainteira050.jpg](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/5519/capturadetelainteira050.jpg)

Comment: Can you give some more information about the div where the movie is placed? Possibly some styling on that div causes the movie to be above the datepicker. Also, does this behavior appear in ALL browsers (because for example IE 6 had issues with floating elements above for example dropdown boxes (and I believe also flash elements))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it...

had to add to the object:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
```

and to the css:

```
object
{ 
    position:relative; 
    z-index:0
}
```

Comment: I think you also need to add `wmode="opaque"` to the `embed`. Other than that, this helped me, so +1

Answer (score -1):

you need to add wmode:transparent to the flash in order for it to appear behind other elements. http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14201.html

Comment: By setting the wmode:transparent you will only allow items to be shown underneath the flash (so if there is no content in that flash part it will show the content below the flash). I don't think this is the solution since the question is about things that need to float ABOVE the content (and be clickable) even if the flash is showing content at that location.